# Progress Bar Of URLDownloadToFile

Tags: assembly, download, masm

I'm using MASM to build a download program, but the thing is that i don't know how to use a progress bar to show the progress of the download, i'm using URLDownloadToFile like this:

```
invoke URLDownloadToFile, NULL, chr$("http://masm32.masmcode.com/masm32/m32v10r.zip"), chr$("D:\test.zip"), 0, 0
```

Best Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wow, you must love pain...  combining asm and COM....

According to [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123%28VS.85%29.aspx) the last parameter of URLDownloadToFile is called lpfnCB, a pointer to the IBindStatusCallback interface of the caller whose OnProgress method will be called to report download progress.